# How to visualize optimal number of clusters from diana using fviz_nbclust

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, graph-visualization

My data is a data frame with 2141 rows and 11 columns:

```
mydatad: data frame
mydatad.diana : result of clustering with diana method
```

I obtained the optimal number of clusters as follows:

```
mydata.nc <- NbClust(data = NULL, diss = mydatad.diana$diss, 
          distance = NULL, min.nc = 2, max.nc = 50, 
          method= "single", index = "silhouette")
```

`from str(mydata.nc)` I get that the best nc is 2. But I tried to visualize the results with no success.

```
P1 <- fviz_nbclust(T2141.nc, method = "silhouette")

returns Number_clusters and  Value_Index, but no graphic
```

and I don’t understand how to use `nf_viz` using the output of `NbClust` as x (the first argument in `fviz_nbclust`).

Then I tried to use the function as in https://bradleyboehmke.github.io/HOML/hierarchical.html , my code is:

```
p1 <- fviz_nbclust(mydatad, FUN = hcut, method = "wss", 
               k.max = 10)
```

It works when I use `hcut` with the methods `silhouette` and `wss` (does not work with `gap_stat` method) but when I replace `hcut` by `diana` it returns an error message. I don’t understand what the default option of `hcut` is and how to replace it with `diana` information.

I tried coding for this replacement trying to follow the factoextra documentation but I do not understand how to incorporate the `diana` information in the `hcut` here.

I don’t know whether the second argument above is `FUN` or `FUNclust` , I tried many options and did not work.

I kindly request help on how to use `fviz_nbclust` with the output of `NbClust` and with a `diana` result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fviz_nbclust(data.frame, hcut, hc_func = "diana")
```